# How to assign lines of text using the combobox

Tags: combobox

So I'm working on this program idea I had in Windows Form Application.

I have a combobox that lists the years 1981-2013. Beside it, a simple Enter button.

I wanted to be able to assign individual lines of text to each year that would be displayed in the message box.

Like if the user selects 1981, clicks Enter and the message box displayed "In the year of 1981.."
but if they select 1982, the message box displayed "In the year of 1982.."
I have everything else I want working, except that I can't figure out how to assign different lines of text to different years. 
Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

First set the **DropDownStyle** of your ComboBox to **DropDownList**.Now assuming that you already have years(item) available in your **ComboBox's collection**,place the code below in the **EnterButton's** click event;

```
        object item = ComboboxYears.SelectedItem.ToString();
        MessageBox.Show("In the year of" + item.ToString()+"...");
```

That should do the job.